# How do I cause SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration to load configuration information from the app.config?

Tags: c#, wcf, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I am creating an STS with the WIF framework included in .NET 4.5. I am self-hosting this STS (for now), using the `WSTrustServiceHost` class. In order to do that, I am doing the following:

```
var conf = new SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration("isser name here", true)
{
    DisableWsdl          = true,
    SecurityTokenService = typeof(MyTokenService),
};
var ct   = new WSTrustServiceContract(conf);
var host = new WSTrustServiceHost(ct);

host.Open();
// ...
```

As you can see, I'm passing in `true` to the `loadConfig` parameter of the `SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration` constructor, which, says the documentation:

> **true** to load settings from the configuration file; otherwise **false**.

I have an `identityConfiguration` element in my configuration file, but it does not seem to be loaded. I can make changes to the configuration file, f.e. I can alter the `securityTokenHandlers`, and those changes are not reflected in the constructed `SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration`.

In my app.config file, I have the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="sts_behavior">
                <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" identityConfiguration="the_issuer_id">
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="7A5D7EB05EC741E45BF4EDA7E574F58DC31EF290" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <ws2007HttpBinding>
            <binding name="sts_binding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustServiceContract" behaviorConfiguration="sts_behavior">
            <endpoint address="http://my-machine:54512/tokens" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrust13SyncContract" bindingConfiguration="sts_binding" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

As one can see, the `<serviceCredentials>` element refers to the `<identityConfiguration>` element present in the config file, and if I change this name to not match that `<identityConfiguration>` element, an error is thrown when the service host is opened. This `<identityConfiguration>` element is still not used, however, as I can `<clear/>` the security token handlers, and a token handler is still used when a request comes in.

How can I configure and self-host a custom STS with a minimum of programmatic configuration?

Comment: I withdrew my answer, since you did not appreciate it, but will try to help you anyway: the Thinktecture stuff is just a wrapper around what you are using and does *not* require programmatic configuration. It has an extensive file-based config mechanism.

Comment: The Thinktecture stuff uses programmatic configuration. Regardless of whether that programmatic configuration is driven by configuration files, it is still programmatic configuration. I want to use the built-in xml configuration infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much exploration, I've discovered that one of the overloads of the `SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration` constructor allows one to specify the name of the `<identityConfiguration>` element from which the configuration is loaded:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Initializes a new instance of the System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration
//     class that has the specified issuer name and signing credentials. Settings
//     are loaded from the specified named configuration.
//
// Parameters:
//   issuerName:
//     The issuer name. Sets the System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.TokenIssuerName
//     property.
//
//   signingCredentials:
//     The signing credentials for the STS. Sets the System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.SigningCredentials
//     property.
//
//   serviceName:
//     The name of the <identityConfiguration> element from which the configuration
//     is to be loaded.
public SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration(string issuerName, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, string serviceName);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this behaves differently from `public SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration(bool loadConfig)`? No matter if I use this constructor or the one you're proposing here, I get the same result: My config section isn't loaded.